# How to extract first name using regex?

Tags: regex

My input string looks like this:

```
Employee: Joe Banana
Department: Sales 
Location: New York

Bla bla bla

Note:

even more bla
```

This regex does the trick extracting the full name, i.e. Joe Banana

```
(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Employee): .*\s(.*)$(?-m)(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Note):$(?-m)(?s).*
```

However this doesn't work for first name, but extract Department instead:

```
(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Employee): (.*)\s.*$(?-m)(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Note):$(?-m)(?s).*
```

Why don't these regex extract the first name and the last name?

I need to keep searching for those groups as we need to stop searching after Note:

Comment: Well... `(?m)^Employee: (.+)` and `(?m)^Department: (.+)`?

Comment: It would still have to work with those groups... because we don't want to search after Note:

Comment: As you see, the question requires clarification. Please update it with actual requirements.

Comment: description updated

Comment: What does it mean you need to stop? When using a `Regex.Match` you only get one match. Where and how is your regex used? What are your blocks delimited with? Just with the "Note:" on a separate line? Try [`(?m)^Employee:\s*(.+)\s*Department:\s*(.+)[\s\S]*`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eEmployee%3a%5cs*(.%2b)%5cs*Department%3a%5cs*(.%2b)%5b%5cs%5cS%5d*&i=Employee%3a+Joe+Banana%0d%0aDepartment%3a+Sales+%0d%0aLocation%3a+New+York%0d%0a%0d%0aBla+bla+bla%0d%0a%0d%0aNote%3a%0d%0a%0d%0aeven+more+bla&o=m) - you will get the first employee name and department in the string.

Comment: Just Just with the "Note:" on a separate line? on a separate line

Comment: Well, I'd use either `(?m)^Employee:\s*(.+)\s*Department:\s*(.+)[\s\S]*` or a more precise `(?m)^Employee:\s*(.+)\s*Department:\s*(.+)(?=[\s\S]*?\nNote:(?:\r?\n|$))[\s\S]*`

Comment: Unfortunately I need those () around Employee and Note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this

FIRSTNAME

```
(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Employee): (.*?)\s.*$(?-m)(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Note):$(?-m)(?s).*
```

LASTNAME

```
(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Employee): .*?\s(.*)$(?-m)(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Note):$(?-m)(?s).*
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Employee:\s*(?P<employee>.+)[\n\r]
Department:\s*(?P<department>.+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lA6nA7/1) (and mind the different modifiers!)

Comment: THANKS A TON FOR THIS!! this little trick has saved me so much time

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, the first match group is the first name the second match group is the last name :

> (?m)^Employee:\s+(w+)\s+(w+)

or replace (.*) by (w+)\s+(w+)  in your regex :

> (?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Employee):
>   .*\s(w+)\s+(w+)$(?-m)(?s).*(?-s)(?m)^\s*(Note):$(?-m)(?s).*

Answer (score 0):

If you use this, the first capture group will be the first name and the second one will be the last name:

```
Employee:\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)
```